# Passing an object to another controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, mongoid

I have a `request` model. When I create a new `request` from a form I have, if one of the items in the "request" model is true then I want to send the user to a charge page. I then want to get one of the fields from the `request` to set the charge amount. I am doing this thru the controllers but the `charge` is not picking up the `request` object to get the amount from it.  Here is my `request` controller.

```
def create
  @user = current_user
    if @request = @user.request.create!(authorization_params)
      if @request.must_pay == true
        redirect_to new_users_charge_path(@request), :notice => "Please make payment before proceeding"
      else
        redirect_to users_dashboard_path, :notice => "Success"
      end
    else
      redirect_to users_dashboard_path, :error => "Oops!"
    end

def authorization_params
      params.require(:request).permit( :field_1, :field_2, etc...)
end
```

So when it passes this `request` to the new charge path, I want to get the how much to pay field out of the `request` so my charge controller looks like this.

```
def create
  # Amount in cents
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])
  @user = current_user
  @amount = @request.how_much_to_pay

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => @user.email,
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    ) 

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
```

But I keep getting the error `` undefined method `how_much_to_pay' for nil:NilClass ``

So I don't think its passing the request to the charge controller. What am I missing?

Here is the charges form that is created.

```
<%= form_tag users_charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: <%= number_to_currency (@request.how_much_to_pay.to_i/100) %></span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="..."
          data-amount="<%= @request.how_much_to_pay %>"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where are  "authorization_params" set? And have you confirmed it's not null?

Comment: updated question. "authorization_params" are in the request controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@request is nil, so Request.find(params[:id]) isn't finding anything. So it's not getting an id in the params to find a request.

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do. I don't see why you don't just use a model method for creating the customer and charge.

Comment: The request is a model. So if im passing the request id out of the request controller when its created shouldnt the charge controller pick it up?

Comment: The request has the amount that must be charged so the charge needs to receive that amount from the request before it can charge.

Comment: If you really want to do it that way, I think you need to specify the key. So you can do new_users_change_path(id: @request)

Comment: Tried that but the charges controller is still not recognizing the request. I am wondering if my issue is in this line on the charges controller. Because based on what I see it is passing the id.````@reportapproval = Request.find(params[:id])````

Comment: Remember, the new_users_charge_path is going to go to a new method. I'm guessing you have a method, route and template for that, so maybe you should post that so I can see what you're doing there and what's getting passed to create.

Comment: I got it! I passed the objects to create instead of new and that allowed the controller to see them.